# Javascript Tic Tac Toe - Winning function not invoking/working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a simple tic tac toe game with two players, I have a isWinner() function to check for a winner(just the first row atm to test) but the function doesn't seem to get invoked even though i have called it. I want the function to alert 'winner' once a user gets three in a row in the first row.

My code:

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div col-xs-12>
      <div id="dialogOverlay"></div>
      <div id="dialogBox">
        <div id="dialogHead"></div>
        <div id="dialogMain">X or O?</div>
        <div id="dialogFooter">
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="cross">X</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="circle">O</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-4" div id="top-left"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="top"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="top-right"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="left"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="middle"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="right"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="bottom-left"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="bottom"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4" div id="bottom-right"></div>
```

```
JS:

    $(document).ready(function() {
  var x = "X";
  var o = "O";
  var userChoice;
  var dialogBox = $("#dialogBox");
  var s1 = $("#top-left").text();
  var s2 = $("#top").text();
  var s3 = $("#top-right").text();
  var s4 = $("#left").text();
  var s5 = $("#middle").text();
  var s6 = $("#right").text();
  var s7 = $("#bottom-left").text();
  var s8 = $("#bottom").text();
  var s9 = $("#bottom-right").text();

  var countMoves = 0;

  renderDialog();
  dialogChoice(); // user chooses X or O
  move();
  isWinner();

  function renderDialog() {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var centerDialog = (winW / 2) - (600 * 0.5); // to center
    dialogBox.css("display", "block")
    dialogBox.css("left", centerDialog + "px");
    dialogBox.css("top", "100px")
  }

  function dialogChoice() {
    var cross = $('#cross');
    var circle = $('#circle');

    cross.on("click", function() {
      dialogBox.css("display", "none");
      userChoice = "X";

    });
    circle.on("click", function() {
      dialogBox.css("display", "none");
      userChoice = "O";
    });
  }

  function move() {

    $("#top-left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top-left").html() === '') {
        $("#top-left").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#top").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top").html() === '') {
        $("#top").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };

    });
    $("#top-right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top-right").html() === '') {
        $("#top-right").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      }

    });
    $("#left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#left").html() === '') {
        $("#left").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#middle").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#middle").html() === '') {
        $("#middle").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#right").html() === '') {
        $("#right").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom-left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom-left").html() === '') {
        $("#bottom-left").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom").html() === '') {
        $("#bottom").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom-right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom-right").html() === '') {

        $("#bottom-right").text(userChoice);
        userTurn();
      };
    });

  };

  function userTurn() {

    if (userChoice === "X") {
      userChoice = "O";
    } else {
      userChoice = "X";
    }

  };

  function isWinner() {
    var result = false;
    if (s1 == "X" && s2 == "X" && s3 == "X" || s1 == "O" && s2 == "O" && s3 == "O") {
      alert("winner")
      result = true
    }

    return result;
  };

});
```

example: http://codepen.io/aliz16/pen/yJgQQd

Comment: You're mixing `and` and `or` without any `()` to enforce the evaluation order, so your win test is actually `s1 && s2 && (s3 || s1) && s2 && s3`. note the `()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because that's how operator precedence works.

Comment: you're doing the equivalent of `1 + 2 * 3` and expecting to get `9` as the answer, when by all rules/conventions it'll be `7`. you need to learn about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Are you calling your `isWinner()` function on every move?

Comment: @MikeC Is there a resource on comparison operator precedence?

Comment: @evolutionxbox There's the one that [Marc B previously linked to.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a call of `isWinner()` in every round

```
function userTurn() {
    isWinner();

    if (userChoice === "X") {
        userChoice = "O";
    } else {
        userChoice = "X";
    }

};
```

Furthermore you only set your parameters s1 to s9 once on page-load.
Even if the condition in `isWinner()` is correct they are always empty.
You have to set or reload the variables on every click.

For example:

```
    $("#top-left").on("click", function() {
        if ($("#top-left").html() === '') {
          $("#top-left").text(userChoice);
          //update your variable
          s1 = userChoice;
          userTurn();
        };
    });
```

or just reference the elements directly:

```
var s1 = $("#top-left");
var s2 = $("#top");
var s3 = $("#top-right");
var s4 = $("#left");
var s5 = $("#middle");
var s6 = $("#right");
var s7 = $("#bottom-left");
var s8 = $("#bottom");
var s9 = $("#bottom-right");



function isWinner() { 
    var result = false;
    if (s1.text() == "X" && s2.text() == "X" && s3.text() == "X" || s1.text() == "O" && s2.text() == "O" && s3.text() == "O") {
        alert("winner")
        result = true
    }

    return result;
};
```